# Python List Comprehensions, sublist row and column

Tags: python, list, row

Hi i have my Python list A and on my List c I extend only two columns, How can i Limit rows so that my list C contains only row 2 and 3

expected value

```
[[2,1],
 [3,0]]
```

is there a way of doing it trought List Comprehensions

```
A = [[0,1,4,5,3],
     [1,0,2,5,4],
     [4,2,0,1,5],
     [1,3,1,0,3],
     [3,4,5,3,0]]

c=[]
print ('Print A')
print('\n'.join([''.join(['{:4}'.format(item) for item in row]) for row in A]))

c.extend( [[x[1],x[3]] for x in A])

print ('Print c')

print('\n'.join([''.join(['{:4}'.format(item) for item in rrr]) for rrr in c]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, pick the row/cols indexes you need:

```
A = [[0,1,4,5,3],
     [1,0,2,5,4],
     [4,2,0,1,5],
     [1,3,1,0,3],
     [3,4,5,3,0]]

rows = [2,3]
cols = [1,3]

C = [[A[i][j] for j in cols] for i in rows]
```

result:

```
>>> C
[[2, 1], [3, 0]]
```

Maybe slightly better because it avoids to compute `A[i]` each time would be to add another comprehension just to name the row:

```
C = [[row[j] for j in cols] for row in (A[i] for i in rows)]
```

that's a basic python approach. If you have big matrices & list of indices, I suppose that a `numpy` solution would be faster.